# how to filter hash in output of powershell

Tags: powershell, registry, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

i am trying to make a powershell script to automatically get the hash of a file for me since i do not want to install any 3rd party applications for it

i plan to put it in the *\shell\ registry to that i can easily access it via right-click

currently i have this for sha1

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\hash\shell\01menu]
"MUIVerb"="SHA1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\hash\shell\01menu\command]
@="powershell -WindowStyle hidden -command get-filehash -literalpath '%1' -algorithm SHA1 | fl | clip"
```

my problem is that the ouput of that is

```
Algorithm : SHA1
Hash      : AEA8544C715835248EB1A5FE782D75D6730BEA9F
Path      : %PATH%\%filename%
```

i just want to be able to filter out the hash part so that if i run the code i will just get

```
AEA8544C715835248EB1A5FE782D75D6730BEA9F
```

without all the other stuff

how to do this?

thanks!

Comment: `(get-filehash -literalpath '%1' -algorithm SHA1).Hash`

Answer (score 0):

Or if not using .Net notation...
(A little longer and a little slower)

```
Get-FileHash -LiteralPath '%1' -Algorithm SHA1 | Select -ExpandProperty Hash
```